# Awesomium .NET ExecuteJavascriptWithResult TimedOut

Tags: c#, javascript, awesomium

Awesomium .NET 1.7.4.2. The problem described in the code:

```
    private void OnLoadingFrameComplete(object sender, FrameEventArgs frameEventArgs)
    {
        if (IsLoading) return;
        SynchronousMessageTimeout = 5000;
        dynamic forms = ExecuteJavascriptWithResult(@"
        (function () {
            var result = [];
            var nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName('form');

            //return nodeList[0];           //
            //result[0] = 1;                // Any of these works fine
            //result[0] = { a : 1, b : 2 }; //

            //result.push(nodeList[0]);     // 
            //result[0] = nodeList[0];      // Any of these returns undefined and TimedOut
            //result[0] = document;         //

            return result;
        })();");
        var error = GetLastError();
    }
```

Increasing timeout does not help. It works in all cases in Chrome console. My test page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form>
                <input type="text"></input>
                <input type="textarea"></input>
            </form>
            <form method="post">
                <input type="email"></input>
                <input type="button"></input>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

no ajax, etc.

It seems that something wrong happens when trying to set array's element to any DOM object. Though returning the object itself works fine. So why is this happen? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: i am also faceing this problem..did you found a solution ?

Comment: No. The only working solution I found is to return a nodeList and process it in C#:
    var formsJS = (JSObject)browser.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult(@"document.getElementsByTagName('form')");
    for (var i = 0; i < (int)formsJS["length"]; i++)
    {
        var formJS = (JSObject)formsJS.Invoke("item", i);
    }